# Do we have a list of Acharyas, Saints, Swami and Gurus by their authority?

Tags: guru

Probably related to this- [Validity of references from new-age Gurus?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/537/validity-of-references-from-new-age-gurus) but do we have a quickly available database so that the general public may be aware of the roots?

Comment: There is no such thing ..and  this is perfectly opinion based .. that is, answers will vary with people's opinions.

Comment: Since this information is constantly changing and the list too long to fit into a single answer on Stack Exchange, Google search or Wikipedia may be the better place to find this information?

Comment: Thanks for posting your question. Can you please expand the question adding some details? Particularly on the last part _"by their authority"_ ? What do you mean by that?And how do you differentiate Acharyas and Gurus in your question? Who are _"Swamis"_ you refer to? Others can understand your question better if you can qualify the terms & the nature of your query better.